# Find a regex to take part of Email

Tags: php, regex

I have the following emails I need to extract a part from:

```
Bestellnummer xxx:
  1 von xxx, 1er Pack

  ------------- Anfang der Nachricht -------------

  foo bar baz foo bar baz         // <<<<< I need this text here

  ------------- Ende der Nachricht -------------


  ------------- Anfang der Nachricht -------------

  foo bar baz foo bar baz

  ------------- Ende der Nachricht -------------
```

There are 0 to unlimited occurences of

```
------------- Anfang der Nachricht -------------
------------- Ende der Nachricht -------------
```

and I'm able to extract the first part with this regex:

```
$re = "/------------- .*? -------------.?(.*?).?------------- .*? -------------/s";
```

But, as I'm quite new on learning regex, I'm pretty sure there must be a better regex to extract this part (foo bar baz foo bar baz) of the text between

```
------------- Anfang der Nachricht -------------
------------- Ende der Nachricht -------------
```

As this can be in different languages, I'm using

```
 .?
```

To match everything between those hyphens.

I need the first occurence of this text no matter how many occurences there are. Is there are more solid solution for this regex?

Here's a

### [demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eL6oE2/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with: `$regexp = '/Nachricht\s-+\s+(.*?)\s+-+\sEnde/s';`

So, it saves a few matching steps and does a bit of trimming on the message.

More solid regexp.. it just works. Write a test to be on the safe side.

- `\s` - matches space
- `-+` - matches one or more `-` chars
- `\s+` - matches one or more spaces; before/after the message to trim the message
- `(.*?)`- for the message

**[Demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cO9qP4/2)**

Comment: This looks better than mine, I'll try tomorrow in the morning and let you know how it works with all the messages. Thank you.